# How to get NGINX working on AWS EC2?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

I have followed [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx#2-installing-nginx) to install NGINX;

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Apparently after installing it, I should have everything I need and should be able to point my browser to my server IP address and see the default welcome to NGINX page.

In the example, it looks like they are using `localhost` but I am point to my public IPv4 address and have tried with my public IPv4 DNS (although this does appear to be SSL and I don't believe default NGINX is exposing port 443) but both just have connection has timed out messages.

Is something I specifically need to configure within AWS or should it work out of the box like the Ubuntu guide suggests?

How can I get NGINX working in my EC2 Ubuntu instance?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic on my instance. I used [this as a guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate.html) to enable it